# Typescript union of 2 interfaces allows ambiguous code

Tags: typescript, interface, polymorphism, union

I want an array to enforce one of 2 types: either A or B where B extends A. How to do this please?

```
interface Foo {
    x: string;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
    y: string;
    z: number;
}

type X = Foo | Bar;

const arr: Array<X> = [
    { x: 'Hello' }, // implements Foo
    { x: 'John', y: 'Doe', z: 42 }, // implements Bar
    { x: 'Hello', y: 'World' }, // i want this to throw an error
];
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript doesn't have nominal types, only structural ones.
That means a { x: string, y: string } is a perfectly fine Foo (it has an x key with a matching type, and any code requiring a Foo can safely ignore the other keys)

If you want to enforce and simulate nominal types, you can add a unique tag to your types:

```
interface Foo {
  _type: 'Foo'
  x: string
}
```

And create a function to easily create Foo "instances" with the proper _type tag.

Comment: if I write `const jane: Foo = { x: 'Doe', y: 4 }` it will throw en error though. Similarly, if my array was `const arr: Array<Foo>`, then arr[1] and arr[2] do throw. I would have to add `y? : string` and `z? : string` to `Foo`'s declaration. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah it's a bit random but the compiler checks for an exact type in a few places, like assignation.